# problems with push function javascript highcharts

Tags: jquery, object, highcharts

I can't push elements into the data array or categories with my highstock chart. 
Any suggestions why?
I get the errormessage: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

```
 var options = { 
                    xAxis: {
                        categories : [],
                        plotLines:[],
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a/%d/%b', this.value);
                            }
                        },
                        tickInterval: 24*3600*1000
                    },

                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container'
                      },
                    series: [{
                        data: [],
                        pointIntervalUnit: 'day'

                    }]
                }
                function getDatastock() {
                    $.ajax({url: '../includes/hent_stockdata.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: handleStockdata})
                }
                function handleStockdata(rows) {
                    for (i =0; i< rows.length; i +=2){
                        var row = new Date(rows[i]);
                        var row2 = rows[i+1];
                        options.xAxis.categories.push(row);
                        options.series[0].data.push(row2);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: could you make a snippet?

Comment: Can you paste the full code? Also, a stockchart does not support category axis.